# [ffmpeg]Input seeking seems result in incorrect duration of output file when seeking value is small with -codec copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I was trying to remove a couple of seconds from the beginning of some mp4 files without re-encoding. At first, I used the output seeking, i.e.

```
E:\>ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:01:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

However, it was resulted in frozen frame for a few seconds at the beginning of the output file(I guess it was related to seeking keyframe so I tried adding the flag -copyinkf, but didn't help), therefore I attempted to use the input seeking, i.e.

```
E:\>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i input.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

The resulting output file was exhilarating that play smoothly and accurately at the beginning except the duration information of the output file was different from the actual value.
The above command was supposed to result in a video file with duration 00:01:00. However I got a file with duration 00:01:05 that contains the 00:01:00 long video instead. 
I have also tried with larger seeking value and it turned out just fine.

```
E:\>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i input.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -c copy output10.mp4
E:\>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -i input.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -c copy output15.mp4
```

[This image indicates the durations of the output files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQj5q.jpg)

I don't know why there is difference between them and hoping someone could help me with this. I will appreciate your help.

Notes:

1. ffmpeg version N-93439-gb073fb9eea, I have tried some older releases
   and turned out same outputs through.
2. The video and audio codec of the input file are avc and aac respectively.